# Drawing ground in 3D using 3dplot

Tags: tikz-3dplot

I want to draw ground at the specific point`(0.25,0,-0.15)`. I am using 3dplot so the ground doesn't look aligned with the main_axis (having a little slope). How can I make the ground look aligned with the main xy,yz, or xz plane? (e.x it will look like the spiral if it is to be alligned with the yz)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}


\begin{document}

%sets the Euler matrix to use an XYZ (yaw-pitch-roll) order for the rotations.
\newcommand{\tdseteulerxyz}{
\renewcommand{\tdplotcalctransformrotmain}{%
    %perform some trig for the Euler transformation
    \tdplotsinandcos{\sinalpha}{\cosalpha}{\tdplotalpha} 
    \tdplotsinandcos{\sinbeta}{\cosbeta}{\tdplotbeta}
    \tdplotsinandcos{\singamma}{\cosgamma}{\tdplotgamma}
    %
    \tdplotmult{\sasb}{\sinalpha}{\sinbeta}
    \tdplotmult{\sasg}{\sinalpha}{\singamma}
    \tdplotmult{\sasbsg}{\sasb}{\singamma}
    %
    \tdplotmult{\sacb}{\sinalpha}{\cosbeta}
    \tdplotmult{\sacg}{\sinalpha}{\cosgamma}
    \tdplotmult{\sasbcg}{\sasb}{\cosgamma}
    %
    \tdplotmult{\casb}{\cosalpha}{\sinbeta}
    \tdplotmult{\cacb}{\cosalpha}{\cosbeta}
    \tdplotmult{\cacg}{\cosalpha}{\cosgamma}
    \tdplotmult{\casg}{\cosalpha}{\singamma}
    %
    \tdplotmult{\cbsg}{\cosbeta}{\singamma}
    \tdplotmult{\cbcg}{\cosbeta}{\cosgamma}
    %
    \tdplotmult{\casbsg}{\casb}{\singamma}
    \tdplotmult{\casbcg}{\casb}{\cosgamma}
    %
    %determine rotation matrix elements for Euler transformation
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\raaeul}{\cacb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rabeul}{\casbsg - \sacg}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\raceul}{\sasg + \casbcg}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbaeul}{\sacb}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbbeul}{\sasbsg + \cacg}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rbceul}{\sasbcg - \casg}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcaeul}{-\sinbeta}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcbeul}{\cbsg}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rcceul}{\cbcg}
}
}

%translation for drawing spiral
\newcommand{\translatepoint}[1]%
{   \coordinate (mytranslation) at (#1);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,tdplot_rotated_coords,
cube/.style={very thick,black},
grid/.style={very thin,gray},
axis/.style={->,blue,thick},
spring/.style={decorate,decoration={zigzag,pre length=0.1cm,post                 length=0.1cm,segment length=3}},
rotated axis/.style={->,purple,thick}]

%draw the spiral
\translatepoint{0.25,0,0}
\begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
    \draw [domain=0:30,variable=\t,smooth,samples=75,shift=(mytranslation), black]
         plot ({\t r}: {0.00005*\t*\t});
\end{scope}

%draw ground
    \tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.2cm]
    \node (ground1) at (0.25,0,-0.15) [ground, xshift=2, anchor=north] {};
    \draw (ground1.north west) -- (ground1.north east);

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Use scopes for each rotated coordinate system.

Comment: Welcome! And you should have a standard coordinate system, too. Otherwise, there's nothing to rotate. (I think. I'm not sure about this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding`tdplot_main_coords` and `canvas is yz plane at x=0` to the ground style options:

```
\tikzstyle{ground}=[fill,tdplot_main_coords,canvas is yz plane at x=0, pattern=north east lines,draw=none,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.2cm]
```